# sails.js enable compression

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I tried to enable the compression with sails.js and I did the following :

```
module.exports.http = {

  middleware: {

    compress: require('compression'),

    order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'myRequestLogger',
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I do that, I am not able to do any request, and I can't debug it since my webstorm license expired... Any idea what's the matter?

Comment: I don't know what webstorm is, but by default compression is only enabled when `NODE_ENV=production`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28085546/291180

Comment: Yeah, I know it, but same thing happens when I start with prod (--prod) or without (webstorm is my IDE, it's like IntelliJ)

Comment: You're not being clear at all on what is happening. You're only saying what isn't happening. Do you see any errors? What are you using to determine that the response is not gzipped?

Comment: I can't see any errors, but when I try to do a simple request, nothing happens, it tries to load but goes on timeout

Comment: yea, I can't debug "nothing happens". we need more info to help you.

Comment: so when you remove the `compress: require('compression'),` then everything works fine?

What does the output from `sails lift --prod --silly` look like?